# Windows: Calling a WMI function using FreePascal -- Working example?

Tags: winapi, wmi, freepascal, lazarus

I am looking for sample code on how to call a WMI function. Does anyone has a working example in FreePascal, ideally including code on how to pass parameters to the function? Unfortunately, the "Delphi WMI code Creator" does not help me as the FreePascal code for creating a function does not work.

Just to be clear: This is not about querying WMI properties, but calling a function like [Win32_Printer.AddPrinterConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/addprinterconnection-method-in-class-win32-printer) (just to name an example).

Comment: Hi, @OlafHess, is there any answer solves your issue? Please feel free to contact us if you have any concern, and also feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer which does help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a piece of Delphi code that set up many of the standard objects in the same way as Drake Wu's C++ example did.

I was interested in that example because I'm interested in edids, so I fully translated said C++ article's solution to Delphi/FPC. It seems to work.

```
program wmiedidint2;
// based on https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/04/21/accesing-the-wmi-from-delphi-and-fpc-via-com-without-late-binding-or-wbemscripting_tlb/
// modified to function as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/95631/wmi-c-application-problem-wmimonitordescriptormeth.html?childToView=96407#answer-96407
{$IFDEF FPC}
 {$MODE DELPHI} {$H+}
{$ENDIF}

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  Variants,
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  JwaWbemCli;

const
  RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT = 0;
  RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE = 3;
  RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT = 10;
  RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE = 0;
  RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL = 3;
  EOAC_NONE = 0;


function GetBytesFromVariant(const V: Variant): TBytes;
// this function is a mess and only works for bytes. From SO
var
  Len: Integer;
  SafeArray: PVarArray;
begin
  Len := 1+VarArrayHighBound(v, 1)-VarArrayLowBound(v, 1);
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  SafeArray := VarArrayAsPSafeArray(V);
  Move(SafeArray.Data^, Pointer(Result)^, Length(result)*SizeOf(result[0]));
end;

procedure Test_IWbemServices_ExecQuery;
const
  strLocale    = '';
  strUser      = '';
  strPassword  = '';
  strNetworkResource = 'root\WMI';
  strAuthority       = '';
  WQL                = 'SELECT * FROM WmiMonitorDescriptorMethods';
  EDIDMethodname      = 'WmiGetMonitorRawEEdidV1Block';
  EDIDClassName       = 'WmiMonitorDescriptorMethods';

var
  FWbemLocator         : IWbemLocator;
  FWbemServices        : IWbemServices;
  FUnsecuredApartment  : IUnsecuredApartment;
  ppEnum               : IEnumWbemClassObject;
  apObjects            : IWbemClassObject;
  puReturned           : ULONG;
  pVal                 : OleVariant;
  pType                : Integer;
  plFlavor             : Integer;
  Succeed              : HRESULT;
  varreturnvalue       : olevariant;
  varotherval          : longint;
  varcmd2 : tagVariant;
  varcommand           : olevariant; // tagVARIANT;

  pOutParamsDefinition,
  pInParamsDefinition,
  pClass,
  pClassInstance       : IWbemClassObject;
  callres              : IWbemCallResult;
  err : IErrorInfo;
  aname,w2 : Widestring;
  bytes : TBytes;
  i : integer;

procedure teststatus(const msg:string);
begin
  if Succeeded(succeed) then
    writeln('Successs:',msg)
  else
    writeln('Fail:',msg)
end;

begin
  // Set general COM security levels --------------------------
  // Note: If you are using Windows 2000, you need to specify -
  // the default authentication credentials for a user by using
  // a SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_LIST structure in the pAuthList ----
  // parameter of CoInitializeSecurity ------------------------
  if Failed(CoInitializeSecurity(nil, -1, nil, nil, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, nil, EOAC_NONE, nil)) then Exit;
  // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------
  if Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, FWbemLocator)) then
  try
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method
    if Succeeded(FWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strNetworkResource, strUser, strPassword, strLocale,  WBEM_FLAG_CONNECT_USE_MAX_WAIT, strAuthority, nil, FWbemServices)) then
    try
      // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------
      if Failed(CoSetProxyBlanket(FWbemServices, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, nil, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, nil, EOAC_NONE)) then Exit;
      if Succeeded(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_UnsecuredApartment, nil, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IUnsecuredApartment, FUnsecuredApartment)) then
      try
        // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI
        //Succeed := FWbemServices.ExecQuery('WQL', WQL, WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY OR WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, nil, ppEnum);
        Succeed := FWbemServices.ExecQuery('WQL', WQL, WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY, nil, ppEnum);
        if Succeeded(Succeed) then
        begin
          Writeln('Running Wmi Query..Press Enter to exit');
           // Get the data from the query
           while (ppEnum.Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, apObjects, puReturned)=0) do
           begin
             succeed:= apObjects.Get('__PATH', 0, pVal, pType, plFlavor);
             teststatus('get __PATH');
             aname:=pval;
             writeln('__PATH: ',aname);


             succeed:=fwbemservices.GetObject(edidclassname,0,nil,pClass,callres);
             teststatus('getobject');
             succeed:=pClass.GetMethod(EDIDMethodname,0,pInParamsDefinition,pOutParamsDefinition);
             teststatus('getmethod');
             succeed:=pInParamsDefinition.SpawnInstance(0, pClassInstance);
             teststatus('Spawn');

             fillchar(varcmd2,sizeof(varcommand),#0);
             varcmd2.vt:=VT_UI1;
             varcmd2.bval:=0;
             move(varcmd2,varcommand,sizeof(varcmd2));

             succeed:= pClassInstance.Put('BlockId',0,@VarCommand,0);
             teststatus('put blockid');
             writeln('The BlockId is: ,',varCommand);
             pOutParamsDefinition:=Nil;
             callres:=nil;

             w2:=EDIDMethodname;
             succeed:= fwbemservices.ExecMethod(aname,w2,0,nil,pClassInstance,pOutParamsDefinition,callres);
             if succeeded(succeed) then
                begin
                  writeln('execute success!');
                end;
             succeed:= pOutParamsDefinition.Get('BlockType', 0, varreturnvalue,ptype,plFlavor);
             if succeeded(succeed)  then
               begin
                 writeln('blocktype:',varreturnvalue);
                 varotherval:=varreturnvalue;
                 if varotherval=1 then
                   begin
                     succeed:= pOutParamsDefinition.Get('BlockContent', 0, varreturnvalue,ptype,plFlavor);
                     if succeeded(succeed) then
                     begin
                     bytes:=GetBytesFromVariant(varreturnvalue);
                     write('bytes:');
                     for i:=0 to length(bytes)-1 do
                       begin
                         write('$',inttohex(bytes[i],2),' ');
                       end;
                     writeln;
                     end;

                   end;
               end;
           end;
        end
        else
        Writeln(Format('Error executing WQL sentence %x',[Succeed]));
      finally
        FUnsecuredApartment := nil;
      end;
    finally
      FWbemServices := nil;
    end;
  finally
    FWbemLocator := nil;
  end;
end;

begin
  // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------
  if Succeeded(CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)) then
  try
    Test_IWbemServices_ExecQuery;
  finally
    CoUninitialize();
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Note that the original (roadtodelphi) page also demonstrates event sinks

Comment: Thanks. I now only have to understand how to make this code work with the function that I want to call ...

Comment: Try to keep it an console testapp at first, so you can post it on the lazarus forum if you get stuck (OR if you succeed, this is all new to me too, and I like some feedback too).

Answer (score 1):

To call a WMI function, you need to:

- Get the WMI class from `IWbemServices.GetObject(ClassName)`
- Call [`IWbemClassObject.GetMethod(MethodName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nf-wbemcli-iwbemclassobject-getmethod) to get the parameter information(In and Out Params) of the function
- Pass the required value to the corresponding through a `VARIANT`: [`IWbemClassObject.Put("Name",VARIANT)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nf-wbemcli-iwbemclassobject-put). Maybe just do this in pascal: `objInParams.Properties_.Item('Name').Value  := xxx;`
- Get an instance of the class and get its Object Path, and finally execute [`IWbemServices.ExecMethod(path,MethodName,objInParams,objOutParams)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nf-wbemcli-iwbemservices-execmethod).

There is also a C++ [sample with `WmiMonitorDescriptorMethods.WmiGetMonitorRawEEdidV1Block`  here](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/96407/view.html), although I am not familiar with FreePascal, you could also follow the steps and convert it to FreePascal.

Comment: I translated the sample and put it in a separate post. Thanks for the example. Note that FreePascal is Delphi compatible in such cases.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Thanks for your effort and sharing your sample.